# return streams for multiple securities in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Suppose I have a table which looks like this:

```
    Ticker Date       ClosingPrice
0    A     01-02-2010  11.4
1    A     01-03-2010  11.5
           ...
1000 AAPL  01-02-2010  634
1001 AAPL  01-02-2010  635
```

So, in other words, we have a sequence of timeseries spliced together one per ticker symbol. Now, I would like to generate a column of daily returns. If I had only one symbol, that would be very easy with the pandas `pct_change()` function, but how do I do it for multiple time series as above (I can do a sequence of groupbys, make each a dataframe, do the return computation, then splice them all together with `pd.concat()` but that does not seem optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby`

```
df.set_index(['Ticker', 'Date']).ClosingPrice.groupby(level=0).pct_change()

Ticker  Date      
A       01-02-2010         NaN
        01-03-2010    0.008772
AAPL    01-02-2010         NaN
        01-02-2010    0.001577
Name: ClosingPrice, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you.  Glad I could help.